# W3 total Cache - Site with query strings

Tags: cache

I have a blog were most of the traffic comes with query strings for tracking purposes, which means that query strings doesn't change the content of the site.

As I recently learned - W3 Total Cache & WP Fastest Cache, both don't cache pages with query strings.

**The question is** - how to make it W3 cache or WP cache cache pages with query string & most importantly make the query strings "ignorable", which means for example:
if we have two hits:
www.example.com/?t=123
www.example.com/?t=333

both are served as one page from the same cache.

I know that I can add "**accepted query strings**", but I don't know if it just allows to cache pages with query strings, or it also makes query string ignorable?
Also - I think this feature forces pages with query strings to work with disk cache instead of disk: enhanced, which I'd like not to do.
So - **is there is a solution (it can be with W3 total or WP fastest) that ignores query strings and allow pages with them to get cached - without giving up disk:enhanced?**

Answer (score 2):

W3TC "Accepted query strings:" makes listed query strings ignorable:
https://github.com/szepeviktor/w3-total-cache-fixed/pull/380

My current list is:

```
utm_source
utm_medium
gclid
```

This way these pages:

```
/page
/page?utm_source=blabla&utm_medium=email
/page?glcid=y349untg93h45t
```

are served from page enhanced cache as for **/page**

Comment: I think this is accepted solution. But if i add parameter "s" (search query) and search something, it returns the homepage. Does it work like that for you too?

Comment: @MichaelRogers That's right. If you add "s" to the ignorable list then it's just ignored and you get the homepage. I think you do not have to add "s" to the list if you want your search works all right. As you can see I don't have "s" on my list.

Comment: I realize i didn't want to ignore them. I needed them to be cached. But the option to cache queried string is greyed out. I read it's because i use "disk: enhanced"...

Comment: I have "Cache URIs with query string variables" enabled with "Page Cache Method" = "Opcode: Alternative PHP Cache (APC / APCu)"

Comment: Hm. I need that then. But that option is also greyed out.

Comment: @MichaelRogers Afaik you can't install APC/APCu if you use shared hosting, but you can install it if you use VPS or dedicate server.

Comment: It's an unmanaged VPS i have root so i can do anything, i'll attempt to install it thanks for all the help, you didn't have to! Cheers.

Comment: I made it! But i didn't use APCu i installed memcached. Now it cache query strings.

Comment: Great! I have the same VPS unmanaged and I installed opcode cache:
# yum -y install php-opcache

Comment: Hehe i had to disable it. Because when a new post is published it doesn't clear the cache for the urls with query strings... =)